# Sticky Header jump while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem that still could not solve any questions already made in Stack.

I have a Sticky header that makes a jump when I move and I can not find a solution. That is, I do a little scrolling and I jump around 100px (to say an example).

My idea is that the movement is totally fluid without any strange leap.

**Keep in mind that the button "categories" on clicking shows several things, and do not intend that the solution superimpose other elements below (as a response from a user who proposes to wrap the entire header in a div and add a height as the from the header)**

I leave a snippet for you to see what happens:

```js
/*=============================================
HEADER
=============================================*/

$("#btnCategorias").click(function(){

 if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:767px)").matches){

  $("#btnCategorias").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"));

 }else{

  $("#encabezado").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"));

 }
  
})

/*=============================================
HEADER FIJO
=============================================*/

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/*=============================================
TOP
=============================================*/

#top ul{
 padding-top:8px;
}

#top ul li{
 display:inline;
 line-height:30px;
 margin:0px 5px;
 color:white;
}

.registro ul{
 text-align: left;
 font-size:16px;
}

/*=============================================
HEADER
=============================================*/

header {

 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 z-index: 1000;
}

header #btnCategorias{
 margin:20px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}

header #btnCategorias p{
 line-height:46px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

header #categorias{
 display:none;
 margin-top:-10px;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

header #categorias h4{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:-10px;
}

header #categorias hr{
 border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

/*=============================================
STICKY HEADER 
=============================================*/

.sticky {

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--=====================================
TOP
======================================-->

<div class="container-fluid barraSuperior" id="top">
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">

   <!--=====================================
   REGISTRO
   ======================================-->

   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 registro">
    
    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#modalIngreso" data-toggle="modal">Ingresar</a></li>
     <li>|</li>
     <li><a href="#modalRegistro" data-toggle="modal">Crear una cuenta</a></li>

    </ul>

   </div> 

  </div> 

 </div>

</div>

<header class="container-fluid" id="myHeader">
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row" id="encabezado">

   <!--=====================================
   BLOQUE CATEGORÍAS Y BUSCADOR
   ======================================-->

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
     
    <!--=====================================
    BOTÓN CATEGORÍAS
    ======================================-->

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 backColor" id="btnCategorias">
     
     <p>CATEGORÍAS
     
      <span class="pull-right">
       <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
     
     </p>

    </div>

  <!--=====================================
  CATEGORÍAS
  ======================================-->

  <div class="col-xs-12 backColor" id="categorias">
   
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    
    <h4>
     <a href="#" class="pixelCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </h4>
    
    <hr>

    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        
    </ul>

   </div> 

  </div>

 </div>

</header>

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to change the `#btnCategorias` whitespace from `margin` to `padding`so that the white space around the  element is considered as part of the element.

```js
/*=============================================
HEADER
=============================================*/

$("#btnCategorias").click(function(){

 if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:767px)").matches){

  $("#btnCategorias").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"));

 }else{

  $("#encabezado").after($("#categorias").slideToggle("fast"));

 }
  
})

/*=============================================
HEADER FIJO
=============================================*/

// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/*=============================================
HEADER
=============================================*/

header {

 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 z-index: 1000;
}

header #btnCategorias{
 padding:20px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}

header #btnCategorias p{
 line-height:46px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

header #categorias{
 display:none;
 margin-top:-10px;
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

header #categorias h4{
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:-10px;
}

header #categorias hr{
 border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

/*=============================================
STICKY HEADER 
=============================================*/

.sticky {

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
   box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #222;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content1"> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</div>

<header class="container-fluid" id="myHeader">
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row" id="encabezado">
     
    <!--=====================================
    CATEGORIES BUTTON
    ======================================-->

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 backColor" id="btnCategorias">
     
     <p><strong>CATEGORÍAS
     
      <span class="pull-right">
       <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
     </strong>
     </p>

    </div>

  <!--=====================================
  CATEGORIES
  ======================================-->

  <div class="col-xs-12 backColor" id="categorias">
   
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    
    <h4>
     <a href="#" class="pixelCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </h4>
    
    <hr>

    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="pixelSubCategorias">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        
    </ul>

   </div>  

  </div>

 </div>

</header>

<div id="content2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried my project but it still does not work.

Comment: There might be another problem that isn't present in your question then, could you share more information about your code ?

Comment: There I modified the snippet with the addition of a bar above the header

Comment: You need to make sure you don't have an element in your `#btnCategorias` that is setting a margin, in your new piece of code, I can see that the `p` tag is setting margins, which is making the sticky header jump